# Accessing elements from HTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-parsing

I have an element in HTML with div tag and an id, I need to access the contents in a JavaScript file which is included in the HTML.

This is in HTML

```js
    var obj = document.getElementById("x").innerHTML;
    alert(obj);
```

```html
<div id="x">0.576308782559139</div>
```

It does not print anything.

I did check the console, and it says "cannot read property innerhtml of null" However, in console if I do document.getElementById("x").innerHTML it prints the contents of div.

Comment: it is working correctly for me. Alert is showing div content.

Comment: If it doesn't do anything it most likely throws error in browser console..Always look there first (F12)

Comment: where are you placing `js` file ?

Comment: I did check the console, and it says "cannot read property innerhtml of null" However, in console if I do document.getElementById("x").innerHTML it prints the contents of div.

Comment: js file is called just before closing body tag and it is called like this <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>